# how to plot using a file with 2 columns of values in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I have a file which contains coordinates in 2 columns without commas between them. in addition some are in the format e^##. Is there any way to easily plot this in python? I tried splitting them into separate x and y files but it didnt like the lack of commas. 
This was the format I had been using

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import numpy as np




x=(

y=(
)
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.title('Spectrum')
plt.ylabel('k')
plt.xlabel('velocity')

plt.show()
```

edit: the inputs look like this in the file:

## 439 values follow

```
-5.9902515439577e+04   0.0000000000000e+00
-5.9674576874213e+04   0.0000000000000e+00
-5.9446638308849e+04   0.0000000000000e+00
-5.9218699743485e+04   0.0000000000000e+00
-5.8990761178121e+04   0.0000000000000e+00
-5.8762822612757e+04   0.0000000000000e+00
```

Comment: If the columns aren't separated by commas, what are they separated by?

Comment: Just spacing. It was outputted by another program that way for some reason.

Comment: better give example rows in the input.

Comment: We need to see some sample input.

Comment: I added example to the original question. the y value is not always 0 however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

```
data=np.genfromtxt("myfile.txt")
x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]
```